# Using workflow to create a new page

Tags: workflow, publishing-page

Using sharepoint 2010 workflows, I would like to create new item in "pages library" = (a new page) when a new item is created in list A. And give this new page name a specified list A value.

Is this possible with sharepoint 2010 workflow ?

What I did :
Create item in "page"
    Content ID = page
    Name and path = list A value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a page with the content type you want to create via Workflow normally
   Note: Go to Pages Library --> Add your custom content type --> Documents --> New Document --> Select your content type.
2. With SharePoint Designer open the directory, highlight the file you created and choose export - then save it to somewhere on your computer
3. Go back to the List you will create the items in, and under "List Settings" click on the content type in question then choose "Advanced Settings"
4. Choose "Upload a new document template" browse to the saved file and upload it
5. Now you can create the WF in SPD - the "Path and Name" can be set normally - no need for adding relative paths, if you set it to "Something" it will create it as "Something.aspx" under the wiki library for example - content type should be of course the one we modified.

Comment: I am the site owner as well as a collection adminstrator, but the "Upload a new document template" option is not available within advanced settings. Is it a version change issue or is it a permissions issue that would have caused it?