# Creating a new page in Site Pages with Workflow and Content Type

Tags: designer-workflow, sitepages

I'm trying to create a `Workflow` to Create List Item in a `Site Pages Library`
 when an item is added to a second list. I have just one content type in the library and can create a page manually in the library but not with a workflow.

With a `2010 Workflow` it errors out and with a `2013 Workflow` it creates a totally blank page - e.g. a totally white screen with absolutely nothing on it. Here's a screen shot of the workflow settings for the 2013 workflow.
[image: 2013 Workflow Settings]

Here is the error from the 2010 workflow:
[image]

This is the only [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162733/using-workflow-to-create-a-new-page) I've found on stack that remotely addresses this but it's not very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had your exact same problem but then I remembered encountering something similar when I first used WFs to generate Word files. So that link is right, but it's not very clear.

If you've ever tried to create documents with workflows, you'll remember that the 2013 ones don't work at all and instead only create dummy broken documents. So to use workflows for document creation you need to use 2010 workflows.

The same is true here, but first you need to set up the correct template you want to use with the content type or else the workflow will error. So create a quick page using your desired content type because you need to pick a page layout--the rest of the content isn't important here. Then set up your workflow and make sure you use a 2010 WF, and specify the content type and then success!