# Create new page when new item added in list using designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, splistitem

How can one let a workflow 2010 / 2013 create a new page with info from a new list item?

To further explain: When a list item is added to my custom list, I want a workflow to create a page with content based on the newly added list item.
ListItemName should be the title of the new page, ListItemDescription should be the general text on the page and so on.

When an item is added, is just click in SharePoint Designer on Create List Workflow. But how can the workflow create a new page?

Can this be done? I haven't found a good solution on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a page with the content type you want to create via Workflow normally Note: Go to Pages Library --> Add your custom content type --> Documents --> New Document --> Select your content type.
2. With SharePoint Designer open the directory, highlight the file you created and choose export - then save it to somewhere on your computer.
3. Go back to the List you will create the items in, and under "List Settings" click on the content type in question then choose "Advanced Settings"
4. Choose "Upload a new document template" browse to the saved file and upload it
5. Now you can create the WF in SPD - the "Path and Name" can be set normally - no need for adding relative paths, if you set it to "Something" it will create it as "Something.aspx" under the wiki library for example - content type should be of course the one we modified.

[Using workflow to create a new page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162733/using-workflow-to-create-a-new-page)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

When I look in SPD > Content Types, there is a 'Basic Page'. It is not possible to add this to a list. What content type should I choose to add to my list?

Comment: add a custom content type..

Comment: Found that. Where can I do point 4?
The only option I get when I do number 3 is: Read only, yes or no.

Comment: @user3004449 Advanced settings under the content type should have an option to set the template.  This may only be allowed for document content types.